# In Java, why Object class object in method parameter can not accept null

Tags: java

Please explain why i'm getting "Method with String param" in output.
And when i remove the comments from display(Test x) method, it says "Reference to display is ambiguous".

```
class Test 
{    
    int a;
    int b;
}

public class TestIt 
{    
    public static void display(String x)
    {
       System.out.println("Method with String param");
    }

    public static void display(Object x)
    {
       System.out.println("Method with Object param");
    }
/*    
    public static void display(Test x)
    {
        System.out.println("Method with Test param");
    }
*/    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        display(null);        
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `null` is a valid value for `Object` and `String`. You can cast,

```
display((String) null);
```

Will output

```
Method with String param
```

or

```
display((Object) null);
```

for

```
Method with Object param
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when figuring out which method to call, the compiler picks the *most specific* method it can find that matches the argument. Both `display(String)` and `display(Object)` match a call to `display(null)`, but `display(String)` is *more specific* than `display(Object)`, so the compiler uses that. When you uncomment the `display(Test)` version, though, the compiler can't make a choice because both `display(String)` and `display(Test)` are equally specific.

For all the gory details, see [§15.12 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).

Comment: Ok..Thanks T.J. Crowder.